# Loading all sub-sprites of a sprite

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, resources, sprite

I'm trying to load all the sprites given the current sprite in the sprite renderer on an object however I am unable to load each individual sprite (2d sprite with multiple 'frames', i.e. a spritesheet) no matter what I try.

I've used

```cs
Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>(AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath(spriteRenderer.sprite.GetInstanceID()).Replace(".png", ""));
```

And even

```cs
Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>(Path);
```

But I can't seem to get it to load the things I want (usually it doesn't work at all but on an older version of Unity it loaded circular loading bars and error signs). I have created the frames/sub-sprites of the sprite.

I've tried changing the path to just using the sprite's name to including the filetype to anything else but nothing works.
I am using Unity 2019.1.0f2 if that matters.

Comment: This generally looks correct, but iirc, Resources.LoadAll needs a path *relative to the Resources folder* whereas GetAssetPath returns a path *relative to the Assets folder*.  Could that be the key?

Comment: What do you mean? Like, using "Sprites/file" instead of "Assets/Sprites/file"?

Answer (score 0):

So you want to load a bunch of sprites right?
Have you tried this?

```cs
Sprite[] loadedSprites = Resources.LoadAll("Sprites", typeof(Sprite));
```

If you use this your unity must have a folder named Resources. Basically what it says inside LoadAll at the first param is this: "Resources/Sprites" and then it looks for all Types that are a Sprite inside the Sprite folder.

Note: Make sure all the .png files that are planned to be used are signed as Sprite(2D and UI) this can be done by clicking of the png in unity and right corner it wil say Texture Type.

Comment: I'm trying to acquire the the sub-sprites of a sprite, not a group of sprites. The sprites are listed as 2D sprites and has the sprite mode "Multiple" then each frame of the spritesheet has it's own sprite (using the sprite editor button).

Comment: Ooh now i get it but then it's weird that this doesn't work: Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>(Path);

Comment: Maybe this helps? This guy used system.Linq  http://answers.unity.com/answers/1175313/view.html

Answer (score 0):

It ended up being a simple misunderstanding.
My folders were all inside the "Assets" folder while they should have been in the "Assets/Resources" folder. Now I can load the sprite renderer's sprite's sprites using

```cs
spriteRenderer.sprite.GetInstanceID()).Replace(".png","").Replace("Assets/Resources/","")
```

It's a bit long but it works!

Thanks to Louis Ingenthron for the hint!